# Dynamically ignore json properties based on condition

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I have a POJO object with a `List<Integer> stores` for example. Is it possible to ignore it with `@JsonIgrnore` based on the condition to be empty or null when returning this object to the frontend?

Comment: you can use @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) annoation at class level . It will ignore the null fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is annotation called `@JsonInclude` accepting various configs.

In your case it would be:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
List<Integer> stores
```

[Javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html) says:

```
NON_EMPTY
Value that indicates that only properties with null value, 
or what is considered empty, are not to be included.
```